# Assigning minimum value with duplicate indices in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, duplicates

I have a numpy array *X*, which I initialize:

`X = np.ones(10) * 100`

and I have an array of indices for *X*:

`I = np.array([2,5,2,1,7,8,5,2])`

and finally an array of values to assign to *X* at indices *I*:

`V = np.array([4,3,5,2,6,2,4,1])`

What is the most efficient way to assign the values to array *X*, ensuring that when there are duplicate indices in *I*, the minimum corresponding value in *V* is assigned.

That is, I would like the final value of X to be:

`[100, 2, 1, 100, 100, 3, 100, 6, 2, 100]`

Is there a vectorized way to do this? Or a method that would be efficient for large arrays? i.e. can I avoid using a loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
vs = np.argsort(v)
uniq_idx, uniq_vs_idx = np.unique(i[vs], return_index=True)
x[uniq_idx] = v[vs][uniq_vs_idx]
```